# Mock historyService call in camunda unit test

Tags: java, mocking, camunda

I am writng API for access to process engine. I want to test that all of the finished process instances are deleted. In order to achive that I would like to mock historyService. The function that I am trying to test is:

```
public void deleteFinishedProcessInstances(String... processDefinitionNames){
    for(String processDefinitionName : processDefinitionNames){
        List<HistoricProcessInstance> finishedInstances = getFinishedProcessInstances(processDefinitionName);
        for(HistoricProcessInstance fi : finishedInstances){
            historyService.deleteHistoricProcessInstance(fi.getId());
        }

        log.info("deleted " + finishedInstances.size() + " history process instances");

    }
}

public List<HistoricProcessInstance> getFinishedProcessInstances(String processDefinitionName){
    List<HistoricProcessInstance> finishedProcessInstances = historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().finished().processDefinitionKey(processDefinitionName).list();
    return finishedProcessInstances;
}
```

How can I mock following call in my unit test:

```
List<HistoricProcessInstance> finishedProcessInstances = historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().finished().processDefinitionKey(processDefinitionName).list();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Mockito.RETURN_DEEP_STUBS which allows you to do

```
  when(historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().finished().processDefinitionKey(processDefinitionName).list())
     .thenReturn(Arrays.asList(pi1,pi2,pi3);
```

or try the community extension https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-mockito that supports query mocking for camunda

```
public class QueryMocksExample {
     private final TaskService taskService = mock(TaskService.class);
     private final Task task = mock(Task.class);

     @Test
     public void mock_taskQuery() {
         // bind query-mock to service-mock and set result to task.
         final TaskQuery taskQuery = QueryMocks.mockTaskQuery(taskService).singleResult(task);

         final Task result = taskService.createTaskQuery().active().activityInstanceIdIn("foo").excludeSubtasks().singleResult();

         assertThat(result).isEqualTo(task);

        verify(taskQuery).active();
        verify(taskQuery).activityInstanceIdIn("foo");
        verify(taskQuery).excludeSubtasks();
     }
 }
```

Comment: My vote would be for the camunda-bpm-mockito option. We have never had any trouble with it and it is easy to use.